# how to bind properties in wpf usercontrol in mvvm pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

i am developing one wpf application in mvvm model in prism framework.i created one usercontrol in one module and i used in another module.i successfully import that usercontrol in my module but i can't bind properties to that user control.  it act as a single control not different control in user control.so what i will do .following is my code

my usercontrol contain 
3 radio button
3 text box
1 data grid

then i reference this usercontrol to my project

```
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MagicHospital.Controls;assembly=MagicHospital.Controls"
    <l:PatientDetailsUserControl></l:PatientDetailsUserControl>
```

then how can i bind properties to controls in usercontrol.

Answer (score 1):

You want your *compound* control to be a gateway to the other controls by creating dependancy properties which are exposed to the outside world. Within the control itself you then have the inner controls bind their properties to the exposed dependancy properties which were created. That way you have the outside world able to bind to specific items on the control, while passing that information on to your target inner controls.

I use Jeff Wilcox's Silverlight dependency [snippets](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/) to quickly create the properties on both WPF and Silverlight projects.